# Can a woman step out of the house?

Tags: puranas, manu-smriti, customs

In the past there was a saying that women enter into house on four shoulders (i.e on a palanquin/doli) and step out of the house on four shoulders (i.e funeral bier/arthi) . Other than them a woman can't step out of the house during her entire lifetime.
Few years back such thing was a custom ,women never used to step out of the house.

Is there such a rule in scriptures ?

Comment: That saying was only implying that the woman enters the family of her new husband and her new in-laws on a palanquin after marriage, and the woman later leaves the family after her death. Of course everyone can step outside the house, but women have more restrictions

Comment: they don't step outside "alone". they can go with husband. there is a statement in Tamil - 'padi thaanda patni' (wife who doesn't cross the steps), that praises the modesty & shyness (aka karpu) of pativrata married women. they would even go into a separate room inside their house if another man entered to talk with her husband.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Valmiki Ramayan, Yuddha Kand, Sarga Ekadashadhikshatatam (एकादशाधिकशततम्), Mandodari laments over dead body of Ravan. She says she came out of Palace on foot, without a parda (veil) and ignoring lajja, but this does not anger Ravan anymore (as he is dead).

> [image]

I believe this implies that women can definitely come out of the house, but there are certain social norms prescribed.